# razor get not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

The following code doesn't work.

The Controller **SupportController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Token.Creator.Site.Models;

namespace Token.Creator.Site.Controllers {
    public class SupportController : Controller {
        CustomerModel customerModel = new CustomerModel();

        public ActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Search(string serialnumber) {
            var items = S0PinListModel.GetFromList(customerModel.GetS0Pins(serialnumber));
            items.Message = "Es konnten " + items.Count + " gefunden werden :)";
            items.Type = MessageType.SuccessMessage;
            return PartialView("_S0PinListView", items);
        }
    }
}
```

The PartialView **_S0PinListView.cshtml**

```
@using Token.Creator.Site.Models;
@model S0PinListModel

@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Message)) {
    var type = "";
    switch (Model.Type) {
        case MessageType.ErrorMessage: type = "alert alert-danger";
            break;
        case MessageType.InfoMessage: type = "alert alert-info";
            break;
        case MessageType.SuccessMessage: type = "alert alert-success";
            break;
        case MessageType.WarningMessage: type = "alert";
            break;
    }
    <div id="result" style="display:none;" class="@type fade">
        @Model.Message<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(".modal").modal('hide');
        $("#result").fadeIn("slow").after($(result).addClass('in'));
    </script>
}
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Seriennummer</th>
            <th>S0Pin</th>
            <th>Ersteller</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ID</td>
                <td>@item.Serialnumber</td>
                <td>@item.Pin</td>
                <td>@item.Creator.Username</td>
            </tr>
            }
        } else {
            <tr class="alert alert-info">
                <td colspan="4">Leider sind konnten keine S0Pins gefunden werden :(</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The MainView **Support/Index.cshtml**

```
@using Token.Creator.Site.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Support";
}

<div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Support</h1>
        <p>Suchen Sie nach S0Pins und setzten Sie Token zurück.</p>
        <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#searchmodal" class="btn btn-primary">Nach S0Pins suchen</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="szeropindata">
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="searchmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Support", new AjaxOptions() {
            UpdateTargetId = "szeropindata",
            HttpMethod = "GET" <----- THIS IS IMPORTANT
        }, new {
            @class = "modal-dialog form-horizontal",
            id = "search_szeropin"
        })) { 
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">S0Pin suchen</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="serialnumber" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Seriennummer</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            @Html.TextBox("serialnumber", "", new { @class = "form-control", id = "serialnumber" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Suchen" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The Model **S0PinListModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Token.Creator.Site.Models {
    public class S0PinListModel : List<S0Pin> {
        public static S0PinListModel GetFromList(List<S0Pin> s0pinList) {
            var list = new S0PinListModel();
            list.AddRange(s0pinList);
            return list;
        }
        private S0PinListModel() {
        }
        public MessageType Type { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note to myself and everybody else, ever, really ever set the `HttpMethod` Property in `AjaxOptions`

Comment: Is that to say you fixed it? If so, please highlight the line of code you changed and accept your own answer.